# Thread locking when flushing jsp file

Tags: jsp, locking, buffer, flush, gzipstream

Under heavy load I see lot of threads getting locked when GZipping and decompressing the JSP file.
The thread dump looks like below.    Seems to be coming from "header.jsp"  which is of size 14Kb.

```
http-0.0.0.0-8080-304" daemon prio=3 tid=0x0000000008bcc000 nid=0x302 runnable [0xfffffd7de7bc2000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.util.zip.Deflater.deflateBytes(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.Deflater.deflate(Deflater.java:306)
    - locked <0xfffffd7e589078e8> (a java.util.zip.ZStreamRef)
    at java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.deflate(DeflaterOutputStream.java:159)
    at java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.write(DeflaterOutputStream.java:118)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream.write(GZIPOutputStream.java:72)
    - locked <0xfffffd7e58524d28> (a java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream)
    at java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.write(DeflaterOutputStream.java:91)
    at com.pinksheets.common.web.cache.ServletOutputStreamWrapper.write(ServletOutputStreamWrapper.java:24)
    at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:99)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:202)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:263)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:106)
    - locked <0xfffffd7e58524d48> (a java.io.OutputStreamWriter)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:190)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.write(BufferedWriter.java:170)
    - locked <0xfffffd7e58524d48> (a java.io.OutputStreamWriter)
    at java.io.PrintWriter.write(PrintWriter.java:382)
    - locked <0xfffffd7e5824bd80> (a java.io.BufferedWriter)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flushBuffer(JspWriterImpl.java:119)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.write(JspWriterImpl.java:326)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.write(JspWriterImpl.java:342)
    at org.apache.jsp.include.header_jsp._jspService(header_jsp.java:2032)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

Comment: can u post what other threads are doing?

Answer (score 3):

A few corollary links:

- http://www.java.net/forum/topic/glassfish/glassfish/glassfish-301-gzip-problem-threads-apparently-spinning-100-cpu-use
- [java.util.zip - ZipInputStream v.s. ZipFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660819/java-util-zip-zipinputstream-v-s-zipfile)

We are experiencing similar issues - our best theory so far is that the Java code (or the way it is using the underlying zlib backing library) can cause a thread to spin off into space this way. So far the only way we've been able to prevent it is to not GZip responses - but we'd rather pay the 100% CPU cost (as the other threads are still highly responsive) than not GZIP them. It's been months since you posted; do you have any other information to share?

Comment: "It's been months since you posted". I am having the same problem. Using Apache CXF on Jetty on JDK 1.7. "do you have any other information to share?" Another link without a solution: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=4627097

Comment: Sorry no - as far as we can determine, having Java do the gzip directly is just not a good idea for systems under load with mobile (i.e., spotty/intermittent) connections. We've found far better results with putting nginx in front and having it do the gzip (and SSL for that matter) and simply proxy-pass to the java web app.

Comment: Re: proxy-pass: That seems to be a good solution. Nicely side-stepping this issue and probably better overall.