# Possible to determine size of file to be unzipped?

Tags: java, android, zipinputstream

I currently have the following code which uses a [ZipInputStream](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream) instance to decompress a zip file to a target location on the phone:

```
ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(sourceZipFile));
ZipEntry zipEntry = null;

while ((zipEntry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
  File zipEntryFile = new File(targetFolder, zipEntry.getName());
  // write contents of 'zipEntry' to 'zipEntryFile'
}
```

Does anyone know whether it is possible (using the setup above or otherwise) to get (an estimate of) the total number of files or bytes to be unzipped before commencing so that I can display a progress indicator as the decompression proceeds? I thought [ZipInputStream](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream) might have a `getTotalEntries()` or similar method but I can't find anything like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`ZipEntry#getSize()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipEntry.html#getSize%28%29) method. It returns the size of *uncompressed* file.

If you have more than one entry (file) inside ZIP file, just iterate through them first (without extracting them), and add together all file sizes. This might be a pretty good estimate.

Note, that if you need to know the exact number of bytes those files will occupy on disk, you will also need to know the exact size of a `cluster` in your filesystem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've come across a `java.util.zip.ZipFile` class which has a `size()` method as well as an `entries()` method to get access to the zip entries. I'm thinking of using this instead of `ZipInputStream` to avoid having to do a double pass through the zip entries. You happen to know whether the two (`ZipFile` and `ZipInputStream`) classes are similar in terms of performance, memory usage etc?

Comment: I've never really used `ZipFile`. But check out [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660819/java-util-zip-zipinputstream-v-s-zipfile).

Answer (score 1):

As npe stated, ZipEntry will get the uncompressed size of the file from within the zip file.

I think what you'll need to do is perform one pass using

```
getNextEntry
```

until done, counting the entries along the way (size and amount of entries), then restart the actual decompression afterwards

Comment: Please see comment to npe's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin solution:

```kotlin
val uncompressedSize = ZipFile(fileName).use { zipFile -> 
  zipFile.entries().asSequence().sumOf { zipEntry -> zipEntry.size } 
}
```